# Determining monotonicity of a function with Complex/Imaginary critical points

Tags: real-analysis, complex-numbers, monotone-functions

I have a univariate real-valued function that I want to determine its monotonicity, whose derivative function has three roots, one real and two complex. How do I determine its monotonicity using these three roots? I can verify that the one real critical point leads to a local minima. But I am not sure if complex critical points also affect monotonicity? How will complex critical points affect monotonicity? Can I just conclude that the function decreases till the real critical point, then increases after the real critical point? Thank you.

Comment: Since you are talking about monotonicity, I assume this is a function from the real numbers to the real numbers (monotonicity requires both the domain and codomain to be ordered, like the real numbers, and unlike the complex numbers). That is, its domain is the *Real* numbers, not the Complex numbers. I.e., you are mistaken. It has no complex critical points, as strictly complex numbers are not in its domain. It may have an extension to the complex numbers which has other critical points, but you are not dealing with the extension. There is only one critical point - the real one.